# Apache, Nginx, ReverseProxy, URL Rewriting

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

- Can i configure apache reverse proxy server so that it load some of files from local document root? Like may be static files?
- Can i used Nginx as a alternate for Apache (mod_proxy, mod_proxy_html, mod_rewrite)? If yes, any links? suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both can accomplish this. You can find examples of configuring Nginx as a reverse proxy under "Proxying Examples" on [this page](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxConfiguration). You can also see a simple example for static content in my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/145577/nginx-for-static-files-and-apache-for-dynamic-content/145588#145588) and you might also want to consider a cookieless domain for this which can you read more about in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/150127/servers-behind-load-balancer/150128#150128).

For more information how to make the choice between Apache and Nginx see [this serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/143238/nginx-vs-apache-as-reverse-proxy-which-one-to-choose).